# Cost Table bases on a Cost & Item Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to create & update a “ReplacementCostTable” which depends on the  values in the “PartCostTable” & “ItemTable” There are many Items and each item has three parts. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Your help is much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartCostTable](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PartNo] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[Cost] [smallmoney] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PartCostTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS   = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemTable](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ItemNo] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[Part1Cond] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[Part2Cond] [nvarchar](185) NULL,
[Part3Cond] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PartTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I have tried this but the result is not any thing like the expected ReplacementCostTable!

```
SELECT a.itemno, 
b.Cost AS Part1,
b.Cost AS Part2,
b.Cost AS Part3

FROM dbo.ItemTable a, dbo.PartCostTable b

 where a.Part1Cond like 'Replace'
 or
  a.Part2Cond like 'Replace'
  or
  a.Part3Cond like 'Replace'

GO

![ItemTable][1]

![PartCostTable][2]

![ReplacementCostTable][3]
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is the sample data as provided by the OP in comments.

```
INSERT INTO dbo. PartCostTable (PartNo,Cost) VALUES ('PART1',10.00), ('PART2',15.00), ('PART3',20.00)

INSERT INTO dbo.ItemTable (ItemNo,Part1Cond,Part2Cond,Part3Cond) VALUES ('2M3-PS-18','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD'), ('2M3-PS-20','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD'), ('2M3-PS-22','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD')
```

Comment: You did a nice job posting the tables with definitions. Unfortunately you didn't explain what you are trying to do. You posted a query that doesn't return the results you expected. What are the results you expect?

Comment: The ReplacementCostTable should look like this:
    
ItemNo        Part1 Part2 Part3 TotCost
2M3-PS-18 0.00 15.00 0.00 R 15.00
2M3-PS-20 10.00 15.00 20.00 R 45.00
2M3-PS-22 0.00 0.00 20.00 R 20.00
   MainTotCost R 80.00

Comment: Throwing some unusable data in a comment is not quite going to work here. Where do those results come from? You need to help me help you. Your ddl is fine but I don't have any data to work with and have no idea what you want. (I am not going to take that gibberish above and try to sort it out).

Comment: I tried to past a screen but that does not work. Then I tried to paste the excel table which looks fine in the comment box. Will try something else.

Comment: How about a sql fiddle instead? The idea here is to make it so that we can have something to work with. We just some inserts for the tables you already posted. Then an explanation of what you want as output. Maybe even just explaining what you want would work. As I said before you never actually stated what you want. You showed us a query that doesn't work. Maybe it is as simple as adding a wildcard to your LIKE predicate.

Comment: USE [temp]
INSERT INTO dbo. PartCostTable 
(PartNo,Cost) 

VALUES
('PART1',10.00),
('PART2',15.00),
('PART3',20.00)



GO

Comment: And? Great we have 1 row in 1 of your tables. I still don't know what you are trying to do. I can't see your screen and I have no what you are trying to do. I did notice that in your original query you have a cross join. Maybe that is the problem? If you can't tell me what you want I can't help you find an answer. Give me some details or you will need to find somebody else to help you.

Comment: USE [temp]
INSERT INTO dbo.ItemTable
(ItemNo,Part1Cond,Part2Cond,Part3Cond) 

VALUES
('2M3-PS-18','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD'),
('2M3-PS-20','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD'),
('2M3-PS-22','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD')



GO

Comment: The ReplacementCostTable should look like this:
Column names: Item No, Part1, Part2, Part3, TotCost
If the value in the“Part1Cond” column for item 2M3-PS-18 in the “ItemTable” is ‘GOOD’ then the value in the“Part1” column for item 2M3-PS-18 in the “ReplacementCostTable” is ‘0’
If the value in the“Part1Cond” column for item 2M3-PS-18 in the “ItemTable” is ‘REPLACE’ then the value in the“Part1” column for item 2M3-PS-18 in the “ReplacementCostTable” is ‘10’ this value is sourced from the “PartCostTable” where the cost of Part1 = 10
Thanx

Comment: How does the PartCostTable join on the ItemTable, using the auto generated ID?  I would have thought PartNo -> ItemNo, but the data you posted 'Part1' <> '2M3-PS-18' and I don't see a good relation via the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @PartCostTable TABLE
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PartNo] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Cost] [smallmoney] NULL
)

DECLARE @ItemTable TABLE
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemNo] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Part1Cond] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Part2Cond] [nvarchar](185) NULL,
    [Part3Cond] [nvarchar](15) NULL
)


INSERT INTO @PartCostTable 
(PartNo,Cost) 
VALUES 
('PART1',10.00), 
('PART2',15.00), 
('PART3',20.00);

INSERT INTO @ItemTable 
(ItemNo,Part1Cond,Part2Cond,Part3Cond) 
VALUES 
('2M3-PS-18','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD'), 
('2M3-PS-20','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD'), 
('2M3-PS-22','GOOD','REPLACE','GOOD');
```

Here is my guess at what the op is attempting:

```
SELECT 
    it.ID,
    it.ItemNo,
    CASE WHEN it.Part1Cond = 'REPLACE' THEN pct1.Cost ELSE 0 END Cost1,
    CASE WHEN it.Part2Cond = 'REPLACE' THEN pct2.Cost ELSE 0 END Cost2,
    CASE WHEN it.Part3Cond = 'REPLACE' THEN pct3.Cost ELSE 0 END Cost3,
    (CASE WHEN it.Part1Cond = 'REPLACE' THEN  pct1.Cost ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN it.Part2Cond = 'REPLACE' THEN  pct2.Cost ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN it.Part3Cond = 'REPLACE' THEN  pct3.Cost ELSE 0 END) TotalCost
FROM @ItemTable it
LEFT JOIN @PartCostTable pct1
    ON pct1.PartNo = 'PART1'
LEFT JOIN @PartCostTable pct2
    ON pct2.PartNo = 'PART2'
LEFT JOIN @PartCostTable pct3
    ON pct3.PartNo = 'PART3'
```

Here is the output:

```
ID  ItemNo  Cost1   Cost2   Cost3   TotalCost
1   2M3-PS-18   0.00    15.00   0.00    15.00
2   2M3-PS-20   0.00    15.00   0.00    15.00
3   2M3-PS-22   0.00    15.00   0.00    15.00
```

It still seems like the part cost should have a more distinct join when you start adding more data (IMHO)

Comment: Wow! Thanks Kevin this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.
Much appreciated :-)

Comment: If this answers the question, could you check it as answered? Thanks!

Comment: Where do I check it as answered?

Comment: Ok I found the check!